# Expand data frame with intervening observations

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to expand a data frame in R with missing observations that are not immediately obvious. Here is what I mean:

```
data.frame(id = c("a","b"),start = c(2002,2004), end = c(2005,2007))
```

Which is:

```
 id start  end
1  a  2002 2005
2  b  2004 2007
```

What I would like is a new data frame with 8 total observations, 4 each for "a" and "b", and a year that is one of the values between start and end (inclusive). So:

```
id year
a 2002
a 2003
a 2004
a 2005
b 2004
b 2005
b 2006
b 2007
```

As I understand, various versions of expand only work on unique values, but here my data frame doesn't have all the unique values (explicitly).

I was thinking to step through each row and then generate a data frame with sapply(), then join all the new data frames together. But this attempt fails:

```
sapply(test,function(x) { data.frame( id=rep(id,x[["end"]]-x[["start"]]), year = x[["start"]]:x[["end"]] )})
```

I know there must be some dplyr or other magic to solve this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, I make a new column which contains the list of years, then unnest the dataframe.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c("a", "b"),
    start = c(2002, 2004),
    end = c(2005, 2007)
  )


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(year = list(seq(start, end))) %>% 
  select(-start, -end) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  id      year
  <fct>  <int>
1 a       2002
2 a       2003
3 a       2004
4 a       2005
5 b       2004
6 b       2005
7 b       2006
8 b       2007
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! And adding other variables is easy; they automatically get copied over which is what I want.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `tidyr` and `dplyr`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = year, -id) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(year = full_seq(year,1))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
  id     year
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a      2002
2 a      2003
3 a      2004
4 a      2005
5 b      2004
6 b      2005
7 b      2006
8 b      2007
```

Comment: Thanks! This works ... but fails if I have other variables I want copied over into these intervening observations, not just the id.

Comment: Could be done with this code, but @Jack Brookes is less typing. It all depends on what you want to do with numeric values for the intervening years.

Comment: @phiver the `data.table`-solution I posted is even less typing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# option 1
setDT(df)[, .(year = seq(start, end)), by = id]

# option 2
setDT(df)[, .(year = start:end), by = id]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id year
> 1:  a 2002
> 2:  a 2003
> 3:  a 2004
> 4:  a 2005
> 5:  b 2004
> 6:  b 2005
> 7:  b 2006
> 8:  b 2007
> ```

---

An approach with base R:

```
lst <- Map(seq, df$start, df$end)

data.frame(id = rep(df$id, lengths(lst)), year = unlist(lst))
```